# Credit card transactions in Yii

Tags: yii, yii-extensions, yii-components

How can we implement credit card transactions in Yii?

Comment: How can we implement credit card transaction by using a paypal merchant account ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not that detailed of what you have tried or you are asking about API or something. What i can say is

[Stripe](https://stripe.com/) 
has a PHP library to accept credit cards without needing a merchant account.

If you need something **quick** and **dirty**, you can just use `PayPal's` "Buy" buttons and drop them on your pages. These will take people off-site to PayPal where they can pay with a PayPal account or a credit card. This is free and super easy to implement.

If you want something a bit nicer where people pay on-site with their credit card, then you would want to look into one of those 3rd part payment providers.

Basic procedure is something like `PayPal` works like

Comment: I tried Paypal's buy button and was able to implement the transactions but after that it is not redirecting back to the site. How can I make it redirect back to my site??

Comment: you have to pass url to paypal button

Comment: thanks, Paypal integration got sucess.. But how can I implement credit card payments ??

Comment: paypal handles payments through credit cards. Is that an option for you?

Answer (score 4):

You may use any number of payment gateways with Yii Framework, PayPal, Authorize.net, etc. You simply need to sign up for a merchant account with one of these payment gateway providers and the corresponding API should give you details on how to perform the transaction.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "Yii specific" payment gateway integration. Remember, Yii is just a PHP framework. Anything that works with PHP works in Yii.

There are millions of payments gateways, pick one, read their documentation on implement that solution.