# Credit card payments through Yii

Tags: yii, credit-card

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Credit card transactions in Yii](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13269455/credit-card-transactions-in-yii)

I need to integrate crediit card transactions in my php site using Yii. I dont know which steps do I need to follow to implement the credit card transaction. When I google about credit card transactions in Yii, Iam getting referrins about paypal integration . Is there any other ways to implement it ? Pls help...     Thanks in advance